# Gremlin: need an efficient query to check whether two vertices are connected?

Tags: gremlin

Our app needs to check whether two vertices are connected via any path.

The app does not care about the segments in a path, or the shortest path.

The app only needs to know if two vertices share a common sub-graph.

**My question:** given two vertices with id(s) A and B, respectively, what gremlin query works well to answer the question "are A and B connected, somehow?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should do the trick:

```
g.V(A).
  repeat(both().dedup()).
    until(hasId(B)).
  hasNext()
```

Start at `A`, then start visiting neighbors, don't visit any vertex twice, and stop if `B` is reached. Obviously, this can run into timeouts (or memory issues) if you are dealing with huge subgraphs.

Comment: thanks!  That works great in the case where the two vertices are connected, but in the case they are not connected, it returns false, after a few seconds.

Is there a step that I can insert that terminates the traversal in a reasonable way in the case that the two are not connected?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "in a reasonable way".

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is...say you have a graph with 4 vertices: A, B, C, & D.  Suppose A & B are connected in a sub-graph and that C & D are connected in a sub-graph, and that no other edges exist in the graph, If I check for a connection between A and C (there is none), then the query is returning false after what seems to be a long time (seconds).   Is there a way to tell this query to quit after a specified number of unique hops?

Comment: Sorry -- please ignore my previous edit, your query was perfect!  I was experiencing fog in the driver's seat.

Comment: You can terminate after a certain amount of hops, e.g. `until(hasId(B).or().loops().is(20))`, but then, of course, the result will be `false`, but the two vertices could still be part of the same subgraph, just very far apart.